# How to activate checked maths by default in a program?

Tags: solana-program

It's important to use checked maths in solana programs to avoid numerical overflows, e.g. `u64::MAX.checked_mul(u64::MAX).unwrap()` would give an error. However, checked maths obfuscates mathematical operations and makes it harder to audit code and check that the formulas in use are correct.

Is there some way to activate checked maths by default in a solana program, such that mathematical operators, such a `+, -, /, *` can be used without worrying about numerical over or underflow?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Cargo's [overflow-checks](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#overflow-checks) flag to automatically panic on over/underflow.

If you're using Anchor, that means you'll want the **workspace** Cargo.toml to include this:

```
[profile.release]
overflow-checks = true
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no way to force the normal arithmetic operations into their checked equivalents.  The checked equivalents require extra handling of their result and this can't be magically generated to do the Right Thing :tm: for all cases.

Further, your premise is flawed in claiming that using the checked API makes audits more difficult.  In fact it makes them much *easier* as the auditor doesn't have to try to determine whether some overflow behavior is being used on purpose.  I would go so far as to assert that any auditor making this claim is not qualified for the task

Comment: `There's no way to force the normal arithmetic operations into their checked equivalents.` What about the other answer with `overflow-checks = true`? The premise is to make the code easier to read and verify the maths is correct. Which is undoubtedly make more difficult when "checked" is used everywhere instead of standard maths symbols

Comment: `overflow-checks = true` incurs a performance penalty, panicks and is hidden away in the cargo config to be missed/forgotten.  if all are acceptable, then that "works".  however i still very much disagree that the ambiguous short-hand arithmetic operators in any way improve readability, especially in a contract context. being absolutely explicit in both intended operation and handling of cases outside the norm will always be more secure